# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar y ocultar texto en un INPUT TEXT al presionar un enlace?

Tags: javascript, html

Con este código puedo seleccionar el enlace, mostrar su valor en el `INPUT TEXT` y no repetirlos en el arreglo obtenido al final.

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Si yo presiono la primer vez el enlace, MUESTRA SU TEXTO EN EL `INPUT TEXT`.
**¿Cómo puedo borrar el texto del enlace si este es seleccionado por segunda vez?**

```js
var arrDatos = new Array();

function add(x) {

  var txtInput = document.getElementById('node');
  var strValor = x.innerHTML;

  arrDatos.pushIfNotExist(strValor, function(e) {
    return e === strValor;
  });


  txtInput.value = arrDatos.toString();

}

Array.prototype.inArray = function(comparer) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (comparer(this[i])) return true;
  }
  return false;
};

Array.prototype.pushIfNotExist = function(element, comparer) {
  if (!this.inArray(comparer)) {
    this.push(element);
  }
};
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input class="tf w-input" id="node" maxlength="256" placeholder="Vida nocturna, el aeropuerto " type="text" size="200">

<a class="btn desc fav w-button" id="parque1" name="parque" onclick="add(this);">PARQUE</a>

<a class="btn desc fav w-button" id="parque2" name="parque" onclick="add(this);">CENTRO COMERCIAL</a>

<a class="btn desc fav w-button" id="parque3" name="parque" onclick="add(this);">GYM</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var arrDatos = new Array();

function add(x) {

  var txtInput = document.getElementById('node');
  var strValor = x.innerHTML;

  arrDatos.pushIfNotExist(strValor, function(e) {
    return e === strValor;
  });


  txtInput.value = arrDatos.toString();

}

Array.prototype.inArray = function(comparer) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (comparer(this[i])) return true;
  }
  return false;
};

Array.prototype.pushIfNotExist = function(element, comparer) {
  if (!this.inArray(comparer)) {
    this.push(element);
  }else{
    var pos = this.indexOf(element);
    this.splice(pos,1);
}
};
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input class="tf w-input" id="node" maxlength="256" placeholder="Vida nocturna, el aeropuerto " type="text" size="200">

<a class="btn desc fav w-button" id="parque1" name="parque" onclick="add(this);">PARQUE</a>

<a class="btn desc fav w-button" id="parque2" name="parque" onclick="add(this);">CENTRO COMERCIAL</a>

<a class="btn desc fav w-button" id="parque3" name="parque" onclick="add(this);">GYM</a>
```

Cuando haces la comparación y preguntas si existe o no?, si este elemento ya existe en el `array` simplemente lo eliminas con `.splice(posicion,nElementos)`.

> `nElementos` especifica la cantidad de elementos a eliminar partiendo de la
>   `posicion`.

Y obtienes la `posicion` del elemento con `indexOf(element);`

```
Array.prototype.pushIfNotExist = function(element, comparer) {
      if (!this.inArray(comparer)) {
        this.push(element);
      }else{
         var pos = this.indexOf(element);
         this.splice(pos,1);
      }
   };
```

mas informacion [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)

Comment: Si se pulsa varias veces una etiqueta, quedan `,` demás. `,,,,,,CENTRO COMERCIAL,,,,PARQUE,,,,GYM`

Comment: ya actualice mi respuesta con el método `splice` puedes eliminar el elemento si conoces la posición

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo @CesarRomero, que estés bien!